# Unable to update the edits while the initially performed edit is in progress

Tags: discussion

While editing questions, previously, I remember that we can re-edit the questions by other users while it is being reviewed and the lastest edit is the one that will be reviewed: to either get approved or rejected.

However, now I see that, as soon as I make an edit to a question, it goes to the queue and any changes that I make to the question after my current edit (which is under review now) doesn't get reflected for the review.

I think this makes the editing and review process more complicated.

Is this due to new update in the site or is it the way it was from the beginning?

> PS: here when I say update, it means updating my own edits.

Comment: Problem will be solved in 237 rep points :)

Comment: @samcarter That is there, but this is something irking me for sometime now. Because, once an edit is done, I myself no longer able to reedit it :(

Comment: I saw that you recently made an update to [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461366/121799), for which I want to thank you. However, I had updated my answer in parallel so in the end I had to reject your edits, not because there was something wrong with them, but simply because my own edits were very similar and I do not know the system well enough to approve your edit and then to install mine. Even worse, since your user name was not "attached" to that question, I could not ping you. And I thought pinging you via another post was not appropriate.

Comment: @marmot thanks for your reply :) yes I know that was rejected because of overlaps :0. But with this post my question is that sometimes the system doesn't allow me to reedit my own edits when the previous edit is under-review.

Comment: I can see that this is frustrating. But you're not alone, I just finalized (more or less) an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461243/scaling-the-x-axis-in-a-more-logarithmic-way), but while doing this the question got deleted. ;-)

Comment: @marmot snap ;) one more back-log! Atleast I'm not alone :D

Comment: @Raaja: Help me understand the sequence here... You edit a post. This edit ends up in the Suggested Edit review queue. This leaves you unable to re-edit the post until the review is complete?

Comment: @Werner except the last-part. Instead, though I re-edit, I cannot see the newly edited changes in the place of the old-edits (ofc, it doesnt happen always).

Comment: @Raaja: Okay, you can't see your most recent edit because it's not yet approved...

Comment: @Werner that part I understand, however, shouldn't I be able to see the edits only for me?